# Jquery limit DOB fields to numbers

Tags: jquery, forms, date

Is there a plugin for DOB fields that limits each field to only numbers and below a certain figure. eg I have there fields DD/MM/YYYY

I need the first field to accept only numbers up to 31 (no 32, no 62, etc), the second field to accept numbers no greater than 12 and the last to accept any numbers.

Thanks for any help.

Much appreciated.

Comment: jquery datepicker usage will be more helpful, we can manage date format their ie show something different format save different format in database, and we get good ui also.  http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: we can give maxlength attribute to inputs to strict length of input.

Comment: It would be great to do a character count on the field so If it's the month field validation would only be carried out after second character is entered. This validation would test if the number is greater than 31. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

It probably helps to know that this is called "validation".

[Here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/date) you go. That page has a demo that you can use to test the plugin to make sure it does what you want.

And [this one](http://plugins.jquery.com/content/better-date-validation) calls itself "better" date validation because it not only tests for 1-12, 1-31, etc, but also tests that the date is a valid date (not February 29 in the wrong year).

Comment: Thanks. Need one that actually stops the user putting a figure in above the range limit therefore limiting the need for validation...client side (with javascript enabled) anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a 100% trouble free solution to what you want to do. The problem is that text fields are designed to take any text input. When you try to override the behavior, you can only partially override, and in different ways on different browsers.

There are many complex issues here. Firstly, what if someone puts an invalid date, like 29th of february on a non leap year.

Also, where do you bind your validation rules? If you do it on keyup, the character goes in, then you validate and remove the character. If you do it on keydown, you have to try to prevent the default behavior, and then replace it with your own logic. What do you do if someone pastes with the right mouse button an invalid number?

Personally, I would use a html-5 style `<input type="date" />` which allows people with modern browsers to take advantage of better input validation, without causing potential issues with unusual browsers/circumstances.

I think it is better to validate after the date has been submitted, or maybe on the date input losing focus rather than trying to block input.